# Tensorflow sampling from float32 and float64

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have a memory issue in running the `float64` in the cluster so want to try out `float32`. However with `float32` I get `nan` after a few iterations in the optimization. I have a Monte Carlo sampling within the model. Now I am trying to see whats the difference in `loss` values companring the 2 `dtypes`.

But having a problem as i cant get the exact samples (or approx) generated fromt both `dtypes`. Here i have a sample of the issue:

float32:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
tfd = tfp.distributions
mu = tf.constant([1., 2, 3],dtype=np.float32)
cov =tf.Variable( [[ 0.36,  0.12,  0.06],[ 0.12,  0.29, -0.13],[ 0.06, -0.13,  0.26]],dtype=np.float32)
scale = tf.linalg.cholesky(cov)

mvn = tfd.MultivariateNormalTriL(
    loc=mu,
    scale_tril=scale)
b = mvn.sample(1 ,seed = 123, dtype=np.float32)
tf.print(b)
[[0.958210826 1.73758364 3.31611514]]
```

float64:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import tensorflow_probability as tfp
    import numpy as np
    tfd = tfp.distributions
    mu = tf.constant([1., 2, 3],dtype=np.float64)
    cov =tf.Variable( [[ 0.36,  0.12,  0.06],[ 0.12,  0.29, -0.13],[ 0.06, -0.13,  0.26]],dtype=np.float64)
    scale = tf.linalg.cholesky(cov)
    
    mvn = tfd.MultivariateNormalTriL(
        loc=mu,
        scale_tril=scale)
    tf.random.set_seed(1234)
    b = mvn.sample(1 ,seed = 123, dtype=np.float64)
    tf.print(b)
[[2.4163821132534813 2.7382581482188852 3.1792761513055856]]
```

So my question is there a way to get at least approx samples irrespective of the dtype?

Comment: The cause of NaN likely due to some value in process is bigger than tf.float32.max(3.4028235e+38), Have you try to clip the loss or gradient value to avoid NaN? did you using any learning rate auto-adjust mechanism, big learning rate may cause the NaN as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am using LR of 0.005 . No i havent cliped anything else except fot tf.exp(tf.clipI()). Can you please suggest me how to clip the loss (in my case ELBO)?

Comment: I don't know exactly what your code are, you said you using ELBO so I assume you have log function in your code, instead of using `tf.math.log(x)` you should write `f.math.log(x + 1e-8)`, same thing when divide, instead of `x / y` the `x / (y + 1e-8)`, anywhere you have 0 on denominator you should add small value on it; and before multiply two big numbers or using `tf.exp`, you can using `tf.clip_by_value(t, clip_value_min, clip_value_max, name=None)` to keep value in range, try to debug and find the line of code that cause the NaN at first place, then clip the variable's value in that line

Comment: Yes i have already used already taken care of any 0 on denominator by adding a small value. The NaNs are generated in the parameters which are used to optimised.